# How to join JSONs together using foreign key

Tags: javascript, json

I need to link a few JSONs using foreign key. For example I have three JSONs:

**JSON 1 - user**

```
{
   id: 23,
   name: "Agata"
}
```

**JSON 2 - slide**

```
{
   title: "lalala",
   content: "lalalalalal",
   member: [
      {
        //here I would like to add json user  id: 23
      }
   ]
}
```

**JSON 3 - comments**

```
{
   title: "nanana",
   author: // here I would like to add json user id : 23
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: None of the examples is valid JSON, at best they are object literals, but alone they are just invalid JSON or JavaScript. Could you be that you are working with simple objects?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not, put your brain at work. I'm sure this isn't so hard. And if you run into a problem you can ask for help here. Don't make us write your code for you.

Comment: Just to extend a bit on my previous comment: In JSON you cannot reference other JSON data, not even within the same structure. However you can easily do this once you are working with native data types, like shown in [provided answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15812268/218196) (at least in JavaScript).

Comment: Hi  errieman ... I agree with You, but my post has been edited, and You can't see my all question of course, ehhh :/
My main question was  - of course - how to do this but in BEST way, but  I would like to know if it is a good solution using JSON in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm considering you have three vars that contains each JSON objects, you can do it like this :

**JSON 1 - user**

```
var json1 = {
   id: 23,
   name: "Agata"
}
```

**JSON 2 - slide**

```
var json2 = {
   title: "lalala",
   content: "lalalalalal",
   member: [
      json1
   ]
}
```

**JSON 3 - comments**

```
var json3 = {
   title: "nanana",
   author: json1
}
```